# Set interrupts that are not GPIO or Timer in ESP32

Tags: esp32, interrupt

I am making a project on ESP32. It reads certain sensor values, stores them in RTC memory and sends them by MQTT after a certain time. I wish that it transmits data immediately if there is a difference of, say 10 units, via an interrupt. I suppose this is not possible by GPIO interrupts and obviously not by a timer as I wish it to happen only if a condition is true and not periodically.
I searched on the internet but couldn't find anything except GPIO and Timer interrupts.

**I am working on Arduino IDE.**

Is what I want possible and if yes, how. Please also give a certain example that is in Arduino language for me to study. Also, if it is possible using GPIO interrupts, please tell me how.

Thank you in advance

Comment: send it in loop()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as an "interrupt on a value changing" since that is something that only exists in software, and interrupts are things triggered by hardware.

All you can do is check the value in `loop()` and send the data if the value is above your threshold. If you want to wake from sleep then you will have to do that periodically through other means.

Comment: could one use the 32's low power co-cpu and an assembly routine to avoid the wakeup just to compute the difference?